# How to create Heroku Worker process with Vapor 3 / Swift 4.1.2

Tags: swift, vapor, xcode9.1

I'm trying to create a webAPI and a Worker process (on Heroku) with Vapor 3, XCode 9.4.1, Swift 4.1 but can't get the solution working that's described in SO "Multiple targets in Vapor Xcode project". The webAPI is working fine but how do I create the Worker ?

Thanks for any advice,

Frank

Comment: What did you try? Do you receive some errors?

Comment: I tried the solution described in "Multiple targets in Vapor Xcode project" with Vapor 3 / Swift 4.1.2 / XCode 9.4.1 but without any luck. One of the errors: "could not find target(s): Worker; use the 'path' property in the Swift 4 manifest to set a custom target path" but adding path doesn't seem to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add a worker and a web process.

```
web: Run serve --env production --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT 
worker: NameOfYourWorkerHere
```

I'm pretty sure heroku let's you start multiple processes in this way, if not, you might have to spin up two instances, one for the worker, one for the web.

Comment: Hello @Logan, yes I know, what you write is correct. But the step before that, how to create a worker in XCode with Vapor 3 ? Is it a new target with it's own source files ?

Comment: Worker is just an executable. Create it like any other executable target in swift :)